# No Rust autocomplete in Visual Studio Code for external crates such as 'gtk-rs'

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

Maybe this question has been done before but I can not find anything.

I would like to know what steps to follow so that Visual Studio Code can show the autocomplete window that shows Rust methods and such, for example when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (In many commons, editors) What I see is that it works for `std` but not for `gtk-rs`.

I was wondering if I would have to tell you in some way how to find the files or something like that.

I do not know if this will depend on each editor or all have some specific files included, my IDE is Visual Studio Code.

---

*...you forgot to include the extensions that you have installed*

kalitaalexey
Rust for Visual Studio Code

```
Rust Language Server integration.
Autocompletion (via racer or RLS).
Go To Definition (via racer or RLS).
Go To Symbol (via rustsym or RLS).
Code formatting (via rustfmt).
Code Snippets.
//..
```

Comment: That does depend on the IDE, you should highlight that instead of Rust. What Visual Studio Code extensions have you installed? Have you tried the same for other external crates (`byteorder`, `itertools`, ...)?

Comment: @E_net4 Thanks for comment leave an update

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the use of `byteorder`. Also, you forgot to include the extensions that you have installed.

Comment: @E_net4 True you have, my fault. In a hurry to answer, and not autocomplete to `byteorder` only for `std`. Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you run `cargo build` on your project?

Comment: @E_net4 I have looked and I do not see it, I have also done `cargo clean`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although there could be many possible causes of a problem with the [Rust extension](https://github.com/editor-rs/vscode-rust) in Visual Studio Code, the following steps should help anyone with issues of this kind:

- Do not use the old extension "Rusty Code", since it's no longer maintained. Instead, you have two options:

  - [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) provides by far the best Rust language support and is already part of the Rust organization. This is the recommended choice today.
  - [rust-lang.rust](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust) is an older extension developed by an official Rust team and is focused on Rust Language Server (RLS) integration. It is not as powerful.
  - The [kalitaalexey.vscode-rust](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kalitaalexey.vscode-rust) extension was forked from Rusty Code to make it more stable, but that one too eventually lost maintenance.
- When using RLS, you might need to build your project so that dependencies are downloaded and compiled locally, thus enabling the extension to retrieve additional information about them.
- It's always worth making sure that the extension is up to date and properly configured. Update the extension, and check out the respective documentation for instructions on how to make it work.
- Check the status bar. If something is wrong, it should tell you so. Open the extension task's output window for error messages. If something still isn't right, try reloading your window.

If there's still a problem after these steps, it might actually be a bug, which should be reported.

Comment: After all I decided to install everything again, it is very possible that your answer is the solution, for others, but I am having some problems with RLS.

Comment: @AngelAngel On that you will just have to wait until the next nightly release. A serious bug in RLS emerged a few days ago that was only fixed yesterday and made into [PR #41969](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41969 ) today. If you don't want to wait however, head on to the RLS repository and build it from the sources!

Comment: @E_net4 even after building from rls branch and vscode-rust branch external package are not working. RLS analysis is finished as per status bar. Also macro expansion like push method on vec! is not working.

Comment: @E_net4 thanks for it. I tries IntelliJ and external package works very well. I am having some trouble with macros but I think for now i will use it.

Comment: Ty. Using the official rust-lang.rust extension does the job and offers autocompletion.

Answer (score 7):

For me solution was to use Rust Analyzer extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer instead of rust-lang.rust https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust

Comment: The rust sources package is also needed for the Rust Analyzer extension to work

Comment: I had to restart VSCODE after installing.

Comment: Now I feel stupid but as Rusty Rob said I also had to restart vscode...

Answer (score 3):

If you're just starting with Rust and VSCode, and want to enable autocomplete, this is what I did (Novemeber 2021):

1. Install Rust extension in VSCode
2. Open root folder of you existing Rust project(or create new) in VSCode (and select "trust workspace" if asked)
3. Open src/main.rs, now in lower right corner VSCode will ask you to install some components, click yes and it will install both Rust Language Server and Rust Analyzer
4. Autocomplete should now work with CTRL+SPACE
   [image: Autocomplete example in VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

Before trying out E_net4's solutions, make sure you are running your Rust project from root. (same directory as Cargo.toml)

I was running :

```
-app
   - src
   - Cargo.toml
-app2
   - src
   - Cargo.toml
```

As my workspace root.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was to install rust via rustup rather than through Home Brew.

1. Install rust [via Rustup](https://rustup.rs/)
2. Install the [rust-analyzer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer)

Also ensure that the workspace is trusted in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the rust-analyzer server after installing a crate by clicking rust-analyzer in the VSCode toolbar and choosing Restart server, after that autocomplete for the new crate worked.